# Parse query string into two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with my code, that can convert a query string into array.

This is my query string:

`key1=['PH','PHILIPPINES']&key2=['KR','KOREA']`

And I want only to display the second row, something like this:

> Philippines
>
> Korea

In my code, it's working but it displays:

```
['PH','PHILIPPINES']
['KR','KOREA
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $get_string = "key1=['PH','PHILIPPINES']&key2=['KR','KOREA']";

    parse_str($get_string, $get_array);

    $colors = $get_array;


    foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
        echo $value."<BR>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: First of all its not an array. Array must be like this ? `$var=array();`

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
<?php
    $get_string = "key1=['PH','PHILIPPINES']&key2=['KR','KOREA']";

    parse_str($get_string, $get_array);

    $colors = $get_array;

    foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
        // remove first and last characters ( "[" and "]" )
        $value = substr($value, 1, -1);
        // explode
        $value = explode(",", $value);
        // remove "'"
        $our_value = str_replace("'", "", trim($value[1]));
        // show
        echo ucfirst(strtolower($our_value))."<BR>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You could use str_getcsv() inside your foreach loop to simplify your code there

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this. 
just simple explode by comma **`,`**  and `preg_replace` to get only alphabates.

```
$get_string = "key1=['PH','PHILIPPINES']&key2=['KR','KOREA']";
parse_str($get_string, $get_array);
$colors = $get_array;

foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
   $x = explode(",",$value);        
   $new_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?!]/",'',$x[1]);
   echo $new_string."<br>";     
}
```

Output :

```
PHILIPPINES
KOREA
```

Answer (score 0):

`$var = array(
          'PH'=>'PHILLIPINES',
          'KR'=>'KOREA');`
Else

`$var= array(
           array('KR'=>'KOREA'),
           array('PH'=>'PHILLIPINES')
           );`

Then echo in
`foreach loop`.